# I want to change the head in this data table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
 <b-table class="table"
  show-empty
  small
  stacked="md"
  :items="items"
  :fields="fields"
  :current-page="currentPage"
  :per-page="perPage"
  :filter="filter"
  :filterIncludedFields="filterOn"
  :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
  :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
  :sort-direction="sortDirection"
  @filtered="onFiltered"
  >

  <template v-slot:cell(name)="row">
    {{ row.value.first }} {{ row.value.last }}
  </template>
   <template v-slot:row-details="row">
    <b-card>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(value, key) in row.item" :key="key">{{ key }}: {{ value }}</li>
      </ul>
    </b-card>
  </template>
</b-table>
```

and this is array data :

```
 data() {
  return {
    items: [
      { Store: 'alex',  snapshot: 'missing'},
      { Store: 'jjj', snapshot: 'hadara', store: 'store 1', class: 'A',  missing: 'missing'},
      { Store: 'tyui', retail: 'hadara', store: 'store 1', class: 'A',  missing: 'missing'},
      { Store: 'ttt', retail: 'hadara', store: 'store 1', class: 'A',  missing: 'missing'},
      { Store: 'mmm', retail: 'hadara', store: 'store 1', class: 'A',  missing: 'missing'},
      { Store: 'zzz', retail: 'hadara', store: 'store 1', class: 'A',  missing: 'missing'},
      { Store: 'aaaaa', retail: 'hadara', store: 'store 1', class: 'A',  missing: 'missing'},
    ],
```

table take **store** and **snapshot** in header from data like this, and i want change it
[image]

if i want change this header with static data ,or handle it from api but with customize it what should i do ?

Comment: that comes from `<template v-slot:cell(name)="row">{{ row.value.first }} {{ row.value.last }}</template>` so, treat as you like.

Comment: I change it , but it not changed at all

Answer (score 0):

You putted Store, snapshot in items.

Fix it refer to code at the bottom.

Hope it works.

```
data() {
  return {
    items: [
      { Store: 'alex',  snapshot: 'missing'},  // change here. you are making header in this row.
      { Store: 'jjj', snapshot: 'hadara', store: 'store 1', class: 'A',  missing: 'missing'},
      { Store: 'tyui', retail: 'hadara', store: 'store 1', class: 'A',  missing: 'missing'},
      { Store: 'ttt', retail: 'hadara', store: 'store 1', class: 'A',  missing: 'missing'},
      { Store: 'mmm', retail: 'hadara', store: 'store 1', class: 'A',  missing: 'missing'},
      { Store: 'zzz', retail: 'hadara', store: 'store 1', class: 'A',  missing: 'missing'},
      { Store: 'aaaaa', retail: 'hadara', store: 'store 1', class: 'A',  missing: 'missing'},
    ],
```